# List of Lists of matrices

Tags: r, plyr, do.call

I'm trying to manipulate an R list of lists which themselves contain matrices. What I want to do is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110553/join-matrices-from-the-list-into-a-single-matrix-in-r) where a list of matrices, l, is combined into a single matrix using either `do.call(rbind, l)` or the `rbind.fill.matrix(l)` function from `plyr`. However, I want to combine the matrices from across the different elements of the top level list while retaining groupings at the lower level to end up with a list of matrices with the separate elements corresponding to the groupings of the lower level lists.

As an example consider the top level list toplist constructed from three lower level lists:

```
lowerlist1 = list(matrix1_1, matrix1_2, matrix1_3, matrix1_4)
lowerlist2 = list(matrix2_1, matrix2_2, matrix2_3, matrix2_4)
lowerlist3 = list(matrix3_1, matrix3_2, matrix3_3, matrix3_4)
toplist = list(lowerlist1, lowerlist2, lowerlist3)
```

where the matrices all have the same number of columns but may have different number of rows. In the end I would like a new list newtoplist with the following structure

```
newmatrix1 = rbind(matrix1_1, matrix2_1, matrix3_1)
newmatrix2 = rbind(matrix1_2, matrix2_2, matrix3_2)
newmatrix3 = rbind(matrix1_3, matrix2_3, matrix3_3)
newmatrix4 = rbind(matrix1_4, matrix2_4, matrix3_4)
newtoplist = list(newmatrix1, newmatrix2, newmatrix3, newmatrix4)
```

So a complete example would be:

```
matrix1_1 = matrix(1.1, 4, 5)
matrix1_2 = matrix(1.2, 3, 5)
matrix1_3 = matrix(1.3, 2, 5)
matrix1_4 = matrix(1.4, 3, 5)
matrix2_1 = matrix(2.1, 2, 5)
matrix2_2 = matrix(2.2, 4, 5)
matrix2_3 = matrix(2.3, 5, 5)
matrix2_4 = matrix(2.4, 2, 5)
matrix3_1 = matrix(3.1, 2, 5)
matrix3_2 = matrix(3.2, 4, 5)
matrix3_3 = matrix(3.3, 5, 5)
matrix3_4 = matrix(3.4, 2, 5)

lowerlist1 = list(matrix1_1, matrix1_2, matrix1_3, matrix1_4)
lowerlist2 = list(matrix2_1, matrix2_2, matrix2_3, matrix2_4)
lowerlist3 = list(matrix3_1, matrix3_2, matrix3_3, matrix3_4)
toplist = list(lowerlist1, lowerlist2, lowerlist3)

newmatrix1 = rbind(matrix1_1, matrix2_1, matrix3_1)
newmatrix2 = rbind(matrix1_2, matrix2_2, matrix3_2)
newmatrix3 = rbind(matrix1_3, matrix2_3, matrix3_3)
newmatrix4 = rbind(matrix1_4, matrix2_4, matrix3_4)
newtoplist = list(newmatrix1, newmatrix2, newmatrix3, newmatrix4)
```

Can this be done generally?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: `lapply(l, function(x) do.call(rbind,x))`

Comment: Sorry Khashaa, I'm looking to join the matrices from across the top level, not the lower level lists.

Comment: All matrices of the same dimension? You should provide reproducible ex.

Comment: All matrices have the same number of columns, but they may have different number of rows in my specific application.

Answer (score 0):

```
newtoplist<-mapply(rbind,lowerlist1,lowerlist2,lowerlist3)
```

Comment: This works here although in my real application I have a varying number of toplist entries which can't be hardcoded.

Comment: You mean number of lowerlist is large.

Comment: Well not necessarily large - it actually corresponds to the number of processor cores I'm running a function on using the `parallel` package.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827437/is-there-an-efficient-way-to-parallelize-mapply   may work

Comment: Consider adding an explanation of why this is a good solution. One line of code looks like a poor quality answer, and made it to the review queue for "low quality posts".

Comment: @Benjamin : the solution speaks itself to your question.

Comment: @Metrics I don't see what you mean? Should I re-flag as low-quality, and remove my comment to you?

Comment: @Benjamin: I wonder what makes you think one line of code looks like a poor quality if it solves the OP's given problem. Please feel free to exercise your right.

Comment: @Metrics: Just trying to hear from you before I agreed with the low quality flag. Since you disagree, I will leave it as is, others can decide.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use `mapply` from @Metrics' answer (when you have too many `lowerlist` items to write out), something like this might work. I've used `magrittr` pipe for readability.

```
n <- length(toplist)
k <- sapply(toplist, length)[1] #assuming that each sublist contains the same number of matrices
num <- seq(1, n*k, by = n)
unlist(toplist, recursive = F) %>% 
    split(., num) %>% 
    lapply(., function(x) do.call(rbind,x))
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick. For my application the number of list entries in toplist can vary rather than the fixed number I have above. Thanks for this.