# stack the data frames on top of each other and return one single data frame

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a function (stackDataInList) to stack the data frame together, but having trouble to do so, some help is very appreciated

```
>datList
[[1]]
ID value
1 a 0.9101742
2 b 0.3841854
3 c 1.6821761
[[2]]
ID value
1 d -0.6357365
2 e -0.4616447
[[3]]
ID value
1 f 1.4322822
2 g -0.6506964
3 h -0.2073807
4 i -0.3928079
[[4]]
ID value
1 j -0.3199929
2 k -0.2791133
3 l 0.4941883
```

dataList looks like it

So basically I need to create a function, and when I will call it I'll get results below:

```
>stackDataInList(datList[1])
ID value
1 a 0.9101742
2 b 0.3841854
3 c 1.6821761
OR:
>stackDataInList(datList[c(1,3,4)])
ID value
1 a 0.9101742
2 b 0.3841854
3 c 1.6821761
4 f 1.4322822
5 g -0.6506964
6 h -0.2073807
7 i -0.3928079
8 j -0.3199929
9 k -0.2791133
10 l 0.4941883
```

Comment: `do.call('rbind', datList)` probably should do the work, or you can use `dplyr::bind_rows(datList)`

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways you can do this. The fastest way (especially for large data frames) is to use `rbindlist()` function for the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
datList <- list( data.frame(ID=c("a","b","c"), value=c(0.9101742,0.3841854, 1.6821761)),
             data.frame(ID=c("d","e"), value=c(-0.6357365,-0.4616447)),
             data.frame(ID=c("f","g","e"), value=c(1.4322822,-0.6506964,-0.2073807)))


rbindlist(datList)
#   ID      value
#1:  a  0.9101742
#2:  b  0.3841854
#3:  c  1.6821761
#4:  d -0.6357365
#5:  e -0.4616447
...
```

Or subsetting the list:

```
rbindlist(datList[c(1,3)])
#    ID      value
# 1:  a  0.9101742
# 2:  b  0.3841854
# 3:  c  1.6821761
# 4:  f  1.4322822
# 5:  g -0.6506964
# 6:  e -0.2073807
```

Comment: @BonaguidiLab It is not clear what is the meaning of the argument `a` in your function (you list it as a second argument, but then you are using it as a local variable in your function). In addition to this your approach to start with an empty list and then use `rbind()` function to add new rows will be  very slow. It is still not clear why the above answer does not work for you. Are you trying to implement this function yourself?

Answer (score 1):

As *@PKumar* pointed out in comments, in base R we may use `do.call(rbind)`. Just put it into a function.

```
stackDataInList <- function(x) {
  return(do.call(rbind, x))
}

stackDataInList(L[1])  
#   ID     value
# 1  a 0.9101742
# 2  b 0.3841854
# 3  c 1.6821761

stackDataInList(L[c(1, 3, 4)])  
#    ID      value
# 1   a  0.9101742
# 2   b  0.3841854
# 3   c  1.6821761
# 4   f  1.4322822
# 5   g -0.6506964
# 6   h -0.2073807
# 7   i -0.3928079
# 8   j -0.3199929
# 9   k -0.2791133
# 10  l  0.4941883
```

Or use `stack` and `mapply`:

```
stackDataInList2 <- function(x) setNames(cbind.data.frame(stack(mapply(`[`, x, 1))[[1]],
                                                          stack(mapply(`[`, x, 2))[[1]]), 
                                         names(x[[1]]))

stackDataInList2(L[1])  
# ID     value
# 1  a 0.9101742
# 2  b 0.3841854
# 3  c 1.6821761
stackDataInList2(L[c(1, 3, 4)])  
# ID      value
# 1   a  0.9101742
# 2   b  0.3841854
# 3   c  1.6821761
# 4   f  1.4322822
# 5   g -0.6506964
# 6   h -0.2073807
# 7   i -0.3928079
# 8   j -0.3199929
# 9   k -0.2791133
# 10  l  0.4941883
```

Also `Reduce` is an option, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16110606/6574038)

```
stackDataInList3 <- function(x) Reduce(rbind, x)
stackDataInList3(L[1])  
#   ID     value
# 1  a 0.9101742
# 2  b 0.3841854
# 3  c 1.6821761
stackDataInList3(L[c(1, 3, 4)]) 
#    ID      value
# 1   a  0.9101742
# 2   b  0.3841854
# 3   c  1.6821761
# 4   f  1.4322822
# 5   g -0.6506964
# 6   h -0.2073807
# 7   i -0.3928079
# 8   j -0.3199929
# 9   k -0.2791133
# 10  l  0.4941883
```

***Data***

```
L <- list(structure(list(ID = c("a", "b", "c"), value = c(0.9101742, 
0.3841854, 1.6821761)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(ID = c("d", "e"), value = c(-0.6357365, -0.4616447
    )), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
        ID = c("f", "g", "h", "i"), value = c(1.4322822, -0.6506964, 
        -0.2073807, -0.3928079)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(ID = c("j", "k", "l"), value = c(-0.3199929, 
    -0.2791133, 0.4941883)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Do you know what I can use instead of ~do.call? Maybe ~apply, ~tapply function?

Comment: @BonaguidiLab To what purpose, what's your problem with `do.call`?

Comment: Yes do.call works perfectly, but I need to provide a alternative solution, so in search for that..

Comment: @BonaguidiLab I see, you could use `mapply`, see update.

Comment: @BonaguidiLab I see no error, your data may differ from mine, add `dput(datList)` to your question.